# How to create an upsert bulk job for 'Account' object in Salesforce? what will be the externalIdFieldName?

Tags: api, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I tried with the below body(payload) to create an upsert bulk job for Account push to Salesforce.

```
{
    "object" : "Account",
    "externalIdFieldName":"Website",
    "contentType" : "CSV",
    "operation" : "upsert",
    "lineEnding" : "LF"
}
```

However, I receive an error as below, unable to find a way out. Could you please help with the correct 'externalIdFieldName' ??

```
 [
    {
        "errorCode": "INVALIDJOB",
        "message": "InvalidJob : Field name provided, website does not match an External ID, Salesforce Id, or indexed field for Account"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As the message states, `Account.Website` does not meet the qualifications to be used to upsert. A field used for upsert matching must be the Id field, or must be indexed, or have the Id Lookup property, none of which this field possesses.

You can look up these properties for standard fields in the [SOAP Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm). Other than `Id`, there aren't any standard fields you can upsert against on `Account`; you'll be limited to custom fields that have the External Id property set (making them indexed).

For contrast, see [`Contact`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm), where `Email` has the `idLookup` property and can be an upsert target.